# Using "jsonfile" API throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream, node.js-connect, node.js-client

```
var http = require('http');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var util = require('util');

http.createServer(function (req, resp) {

    if (req.method === "GET") {
        var file = "./files/file1.json";
        jsonfile.readFile(file, function (err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.dir(obj);
        });
    }
}).listen(9000);
```

---

HERE IS MY FILE:

```
{
  "Person": {
    "firstName": "Fawad",
    "lastName": "Surosh"
  }
}
```

---

I spent the whole day but couldn't figure it out. It throws an error stating:

> SyntaxError: ./files/file1.json: unexpected token ?

Comment: you have unicode characters in your json file. copy paste your json data `jsonlint.com` and from there paste json in your file.

Comment: Your solution partly worked for me. I recreated the file in np++ and it succeeded.

Comment: Tip: IMHO you don't really need to use a module like `jsonfile`. All you need is `fs.readFile()` and `JSON.parse()` in a try-catch block.